# WPF - Multi-stroke using inkcanvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to build WPF multi-touch drawing app that user can use many fingers to draw strokes.

So, I tried to use inkcanvas but it can draw only single stroke.

> using System.Windows.Ink;

How do I use [inkcanvas](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/inkcanvas_pg1.htm) to draw multi-stroke?

Thanks,

Hong Limp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Windows 7 and are using WPF4, you should be able to use multi-touch if your input device supports it.  If your input device does not support multi-touch, you can simulate it with two mice using the HID device from [Multi-Touch Vista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/) by following these instructions:

- [Step by Step Tutorial : Installing Multi-Touch Simulator for Silverlight Phone 7](http://michaelsync.net/2010/04/06/step-by-step-tutorial-installing-multi-touch-simulator-for-silverlight-phone-7)

As the article demonstrates, you can test your multi-touch input driver on Windows 7 using the classic Paint application.

**Update:**

Alas, I can confirm that an `InkCanvas` in WPF4 does not support multiple strokes, only multi-touch gestures.  However, I did find and test a sample that provides a similar effect:

- [Introduction to WPF 4 Multitouch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/11/04/introduction-to-wpf-4-multitouch.aspx)

Download the sample and use the TouchDrawing project.

Comment: My device supports multi-touch but I cannot draw multi-stroke using inkcanvas.

Comment: Does multi-touch work in MSPAINT.EXE, as demonstrated in the tutorial?  Are you using Windows 7 and WPF4?  If all this is true, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Yes, I use Windows 7 and WPF4. Multi-touch work in MSPAINT.EXE

Comment: See my updated answer for a possible alternative to InkCanvas.